# XmlSchema.Read does not load xsd correctly

Tags: c#, xsd

I am tring to load an xsd file using XmlSchema.Read. It runs without error, and I can see that it reads the namespace from the file, but I cannot read any other data from the xsd file.

Here is my code:

```
public XmlSchema GetXSDFileAsXMLSchema()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(fs, new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack));
        return schema;
    }

    private void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        return; 
    }
```

Anybody know why the count of elements is 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN says that elements only gets filled after you call Compile(). Before that, you can use the raw elements of the schema, like Items.

Comment: In addition, he should put that `FileStream` into a `using` block.

Comment: [IntelliSence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) [says](http://pbrd.co/PoD1HN) that [`Compile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.compile.aspx) methods are deprecated.

Comment: @AgentFire You are right, Compile() methods of XmlSchema are deprecated. XmlSchemaSet.Compile() methods should be used.